# Load an iframe based on a process variable (url) in camunda tasklist task

Tags: javascript, forms, iframe, pipeline, camunda

I am using camunda bpm.
I would like to have an iframe embedded in a user task form.
The url is set as a process variable.
So is it possible to use the process variable as the "src" field in the iframe tag?

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Comment: Yep. camunda-bpm has a backend and "Tasklist" is part of the frontend.
So the backend generates a URL as a variable and the frontend has to use it. I found out what I have to do and I will describe it soon.

Comment: @markspace You are right. THX for fixing the tag... Maybe you should provide a little more context on comments ;-)

Comment: @eventhorizon could you share your solution ?